# How to get data from the kaggle datasets site by entering the command on the Google Colab?

Tags: python, pandas, github, google-colaboratory, kaggle

The question here is that we get service from the Github site by entering the quick command:

```
git clone “URL”
```

But What should we write to get the data set and convert it into a template from the kaggle site??
Google colab

```
kaggle clone “URL” ??
```

Comment: I believe you can download datasets directly from the Kaggle website, in some specified format. If you want to use the command line, use `curl`

Comment: But how do you know?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Kaggle API. [Refer here](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api#download-competition-files)

```
kaggle competitions download favorita-grocery-sales-forecasting
```

or

```
kaggle competitions download favorita-grocery-sales-forecasting -f test.csv.7z
```

NOTE: you will need to accept competition rules at `https://www.kaggle.com/c/<competition-name>/rules`.